# Can we create and access more than one table in SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need two tables in my application.

Can I create more than one table in SQLite?

Comment: Definitely! You could even create two separate *databases* if you wished!

Comment: two tables in one database? preposterous!

Comment: actually i am using a table to save the profiles of individuals.In future i may want to use another table to maintain their precentages and other stuff.

Comment: Does SQLite have any restrictions(space to store)?

Comment: no its haven't to any restriction

Comment: @MPelletier Why not go the extra mile and fix the *rest* of the question?!

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't notice. I invite *you* to fix the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have multiple tables and databases even.

```
Android does not impose any limitations beyond the standard SQLite concepts.
```

as can be read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

**YES** you can... And even more, practically number of tables is unlimited